# OTG Drivers To non-otg Android Phone.?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, usb-on-the-go

[image]

My Phone Details :

Android 5.1 Lollipop

Model No - LS-4005

Model- LYF FLAME 6

My phone doesn't support otg drive.
Can I install otg support manually ?
If yes, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel has to support it, so a custom kernel would have to have the necessary modification/modules to allow OTG (meaning that you would have to download the source, modify it, compile it, flash it to device).  Otherwise the manufacturer would have to implement it.

Comment: Where I Find Suitable Kernal To My device And How To Modify it.

Comment: No idea, you'll have to look online and see if that even exists.  Try XDA Developers.